# Error trying Debug web application with Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat

i have a little problem with my web application in eclipse. I can run my webapp on Tomcat 9.0, but i can't debug it on server. I don't understand if it is an Eclipse configuration problem or a compatibility problem between Tomcat and Eclipse.

When i try to debug on Tomcat it appears this error
[image: Start problem]

I hope someone could help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Which versions of Eclipse and Tomcat are involved?

Comment: Eclipse: Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913
Tomcat Version : Tomcat 9.0